# Opening Track Output Window on pro tools using applescript

Tags: applescript, audio

I am trying to create some Applescript lines to do some basic automation in pro tools and I was wondering if you guys can help out.

I am trying to open the Track output window dialog but I can't seem to figure out a way to run the code on the selected track.

For example, right now I am telling system events to check for the first window of pro tools and execute different functions based on the answer it got using an if-else statement. Within that, if statement, I've figured out that it's probably the best to get the dialog by clicking on that UI element. (I can't think of any other way. If there is a way please let me know.)

```
click button "Output Window button" of group "Audio IO" of group "Audio 1 - Audio Track " of window 1 of application process "Pro Tools"
```

I currently have it set up like this.

I am wondering if there is a way to make the section `of group "Audio 1 - Audio Track "` into a variable so that it will apply that in the currently selected track instead of a specific track like how it is right now.

I'll attack the full code below just in case.

```
tell application "System Events"
    
    set windowName to name of window 1 of application process "Pro Tools"
    set nameMatch1 to "Edit:"
    set nameMatch2 to "Mix:"
    
    if (windowName does not contain nameMatch1) or (windowName does not contain nameMatch2) then
        
        set windowTwoName to name of window 2 of application process "Pro Tools"
        
        if (windowName contains nameMatch1) then
            click button "Output Window button" of group "Audio IO" of group "Audio 1 - Audio Track " of window 1 of application process "Pro Tools" -- This is wehre I need your help.
        else if (windowTwoName contains nameMatch1) then
            click button "Output Window button" of group "Audio IO" of group "Audio 1 - Audio Track " of window 2 of application process "Pro Tools"
        else if (windowName contains nameMatch2) then
            click button "Output Window button" of group "Audio 1 - Audio Track " of window 1 of application process "Pro Tools"
        else if (windowTwoName contains nameMatch2) then
            click button "Output Window button" of group "Audio 1 - Audio Track " of window 2 of application process "Pro Tools"
        end if
        
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: I don't use ProTools personally - always been Cubase/Logic, since they were invented - but aren't all DAWs these days hot-keyed out the wazzoo? Are you certain there's no in-app way to do this? [Back in the old days, we used to do everything with QuicKeys but the DAWs have beaten us on that front in the past decade or so ;-)

Comment: Yea unfortunately as far as I know there isn't a shortcut for that. I mean it's a quick drag and a click away but I'm just finding ways to get quicker.